# Why the debug button doesn't display for some of the firefox addons

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm a freshman to firefox addon development and try to start with tweak and look some existing addons in the browser by enable the addon debugging support in the developer tool in firefox as the picture shown.
[image: enable the firefox addon debugging option]

The debug button is displayed but it is not added for every addons.
[image: the debug button is displayed but not for every addons]

Could someone tell me the reason? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a good question, ive been doing addon for years ive never used this debug feature. I think it opens it up in the "browser toolbox" via remote connection so you can put breakpoints in your code. I never had the need to, but i think thats what it does. Im not sure why all addons dont have it, thats interesting.

Comment: @Noitidart, yes the debugger use remote connection to debug the code. I want to known if there is some extension settings relative to enable the debugging. Waiting someone help me :^D.

Comment: After several weeks investigation and read the documents about the Firefox addon development. The reason is that the addon can't display debug button is due to they are composed with native XPCOM which is called legacy addon. To support latest debug feature, the addons required to develop with Addon SDK or follow the boostrap format. In the future, all the Addon development should use the Web Extension API which is currently under development by mozilla. Wish this will help someone just like me.

Comment: Thanks @Erxin for that, really appreciate your weeks of hard work and sharing that knowledge with us. Wish someone could have been there for you :(

Comment: @Noitidart there will be a dark ages in the next year for all the Firefox Addon developers. They have to migrate their addons to web Extension API in 2016. It seems that google have won the war of browsers. Anyway thank you and good luck to all of them. :)

Comment: @Erxin excellent .you can answer your question your self .do your guys know how can we see errors if we cannot debug it cuz there is no debug button for it ??

Comment: @FastSnail as I known for the addon with Native XPCOM we could use a debug tool which is called Tiny JavaScript Debugger. It is a Firefox addon too and it could be installed as same as the other addon. It support JavaScript debugging after your addon is loaded. For the native parts, we could attach the debug process to running Firefox process.